# Controlling the page from reaching the top of the page

Tags: asp.net

I have a registration page with many fields and DDl's when i scroll down and select the ddl value then the page going to top of the page and again i have to scroll to the control and have to select the page.How to control the page by stopping at the control even though the value is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` in Page directive

Something like this

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

to know more about this [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx).

Alternatively you can, put this in `Web.config` to make this setting global, By this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
    </pages>
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```